# Automated ggplot2 example gallery in knitr

Tags: r, ggplot2, knitr

I'm trying to produce a gallery of `ggplot2` geoms using `knitr`. In order to do this quickly I thought to use the built-in `example`s to populate the content.

After some trial and error I've got to this point:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,titlepage]{tufte-handout}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{alltt}

<<setup, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE>>=
options(replace.assign=TRUE,tidy=TRUE)
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
library(scales)
geoms <- setdiff(apropos("^geom_"),"geom_blank")
@

\title{ggplot2 Gallery}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

<<examples, echo=FALSE, comment=NA>>=
for(i in geoms){
    writeLines(paste0("\\section{",gsub("_","\\\\_",i),"}"))
    do.call("example",list(i))
}
@

\end{document}
```

But there are still a number of issues I can't resolve:

- I can't seem to be able to mix `markup` and `asis` results options within the chunk so that section headings get produced. (This will be crucial for navigation of the document later). Is there any other way of producing writing LaTex within the chunk?
- There are some examples which throw errors (which is why `geom_blank` is excluded). The [knitr documentation](http://yihui.name/knitr/options) states that computation continues in the case of errors, but it only seems to be the knit process which continues; the example loop ceases at that point. Is there a way to avoid the parts of the examples that are errors?
- The `example` code output isn't syntaxed highlighted. (Useful but not essential).

Comment: no you cannot mix up `markup` and `asis`; I'm surprised ggplot2 passed R CMD check when there was an error in `geom_blank`; I think the best way to do this is to use `knitr` and its brew syntax to produce an Rnw document with examples code and then compile it. This is pretty interesting, and I'll come back later if you have not figured it out by then.

Comment: Wrap calls in ?try for the second problem. The errors will be bypassed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

See [021-ggplot2-geoms.Rnw](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/021-ggplot2-geoms.Rnw) for the full code. The basic idea is to construct the code chunks before knit them. The code is short, so probably I do not need to explain it too much.

In theory you should be able to get something like this (more than 200 pages of `ggplot2` examples):

[image: ggplot2 geoms generated by knitr]

Comment: That works great, thanks! Didn't realise you could `knit` recursively! Just to clarify, what did you mean about not using `tidy`?

Comment: I mean my impression is that `ggplot2` users often know how to organize their R code carefully, so no need to use `formatR` to automatically reformat the code. At least Hadley has arranged the examples code reasonably well. `tidy=TRUE` is for lazy users only (no spaces, no indent, ugly long lines, hopeless to read...)

Comment: Ah, well unfortuntely, that's me!

Comment: in fact I'm lazy too, and that is why I made `tidy=TRUE` by default; I only format my code when I write packages

Comment: I get `Error: at 021-ggplot2-geoms.Rnw:26, character argument expected`. (R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10); Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit); knitr_1.6; MiKTeX 2.9)

Comment: @jbaums Can you try the current development version? https://github.com/yihui/knitr

Comment: No change - I get the same error with knitr_1.6.21, with a fresh session.

Comment: @jbaums Thanks. Could you file an issue to https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/issues with your `sessionInfo()` after `library(ggplot2);library(knitr)`?