# Changing the Color of negative numbers to Red in a table generated with xtable()?

Tags: r, knitr, xtable

I'm writing a report in R with knitr. I'm using xtable() to generate tables in the report. One of my tables includes both negative and positive numbers. I'd like to change the color of negative numbers into red. How can I do that?
Obviously, one easy solution is to change the latex code that xtable generates BUT note that I have an auto-report that numbers can change with new datasets and I don't want to manually set the colors.

Here is a simple code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<simpleExamp, results=tex, echo=FALSE>>=
library(knitr)
library(xtable)
testMatrix <- matrix(c(sample(-10:10,10)), ncol = 2)
xtable(testMatrix)
@
\end{document}
```

How can I make the negative numbers Red?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use `capture.output()` to capture the lines printed by the (implicit) call to `print.xtable()`. Then apply `gsub()` to the output, using a pattern and replacement that surround each negative number with `\textcolor{red}{}`. Finally, use `cat()` with `sep="\n"` to write the modified lines out to the `*.tex` file.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<simpleExamp, results="asis", echo=FALSE>>=
library(knitr)
library(xtable)
testMatrix <- matrix(c(sample(-10:10,10)), ncol = 2)
## I added the following three lines
xt <- capture.output(xtable(testMatrix))
xt_mod <- gsub("(\\s|^)(-\\d*)", "\\1\\\\textcolor{red}{\\2}", xt)
cat(xt_mod, sep="\n")
@
\end{document}
```

(Note also that I replaced `results=tex` with `results="asis"`, which **knitr** 'prefers' and which it will more quickly process.)

---

**Edit:** Adding an image of the resulting table. (Getting it in an SO-ready form required a few tweaks to the code, which is also included below.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\renewenvironment{table}{}{}% Ignore `table` environment in standalone mode.
\begin{document}
<<simpleExamp, results="asis", echo=FALSE>>=
library(knitr)
library(xtable)
cat("\\Huge\n\n")
testMatrix <- matrix(c(sample(-10:10,10)), ncol = 2)
## I added the following three lines
xt <- capture.output(print.xtable(xtable(testMatrix), table.placement=NULL))
xt_mod <- gsub("(\\s|^)(-\\d*)", "\\1\\\\textcolor{red}{\\2}", xt)
cat(xt_mod, sep="\n")
@
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wonderful. Very nice answer. Your answer gave me a good idea for many other problems I've been thinking about for a while.

Comment: @Sepehr -- Was using `capture.output()` the key bit?

Comment: It was. I didn't know the function existed. Now I can customize my tables easily. Again, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Is this supposed to work when 'knitr' is loaded in a console session and the above code pasted with enclosing quotes inside `knit()`?

Comment: @DWin -- Nope. The workflow is similar to `Sweave`'s, in that you: (1) Put the code in a file (calling it `"eg.Rnw"`, for example); (2) do `knit("eg.Rnw")` (perhaps from a console session); then (3) run LaTeX on `"eg.tex"`, the resulting `*.tex` file.

Comment: Should `Hmisc::latex(knit(readLines("eg.Rnw"))` work? Assuming, of course, that "eg.Rnw" is in the working directory.

Comment: @Dwin -- According to `?knit`, that `input` argument has to be the "path of the input file", so `knit(readLines("eg.Rnw"))` won't work, but `knit("eg.Rnw")` will. Not sure what you're trying to do, but perhaps [this interesting script](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/021-ggplot2-geoms.Rnw) (linked to by Yihui in his answer to [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653573/automated-ggplot2-example-gallery-in-knitr)) will give you some ideas.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at it but readers of this dialog should NOT expect Hmisc::latex(knit("eg.Rnw")) to "work", unless that is they are expecting a nice latex table that has a single entry "eg.Rnw". I'm guessing that `latex()` is given the file name as the value of the `knit()` call.

Answer (score 4):

Copied Josh O'Brien's answer with a little tweak to color a table with decimals:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<simpleExamp, results="asis", echo=FALSE>>=
library(knitr)
library(xtable)
testMatrix <- matrix(c(sample(-10:10,10)), ncol = 2)*1.1
## I added the following three lines
xt <- capture.output(xtable(testMatrix))
xt_mod <- gsub("(\\s|^)(-\\d\\.\\d*)", "\\1\\\\textcolor{red}{\\2}", xt)
cat(xt_mod, sep="\n")
@
\end{document}
```