# Can xtable produce \captionof instead of \caption?

Tags: r, latex, xtable

Having read the docs I think this is unlikely, but decide to ask regardless.

I'm writing a poster, and the `tabular` has to stay within the `center` environment instead of `table` environment. (The `table` environment is a float, which does not work within the boxes of a poster).

This leads to the need for `\captionof` instead of `\caption` to put a caption inside a `center` environment. Is `xtable` capable of such a thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\caption` is hard coded. See source of `print.xtable.R`.

```
if (tabular.environment == "longtable" && caption.placement == "top") {
            if (is.null(short.caption)){
                BCAPTION <- "\\caption{"
            } else {
                BCAPTION <- paste("\\caption[", short.caption, "]{", sep = "")
            }
```

Way around this would be to do `gsub` on the result before you pass it to the interpreter. Something along the lines of `gsub("\\caption", "\captionof", x)`.

Comment: Nice idea on `gsub`, but at which point do I insert it? I'm doing `print(xtable(my.df), file="my_table.tex")`.

Comment: Save the `print` statement to a variable, run `gsub` through it and then export to `.tex` (for example using `cat(..., file = "my_table.tex")`.

Comment: @Heisenberg -- [Here's an example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148770/changing-the-color-of-negative-numbers-to-red-in-a-table-generated-with-xtable/12148962#12148962) that accomplishes this type of thing using `capture.output()`, `gsub()`, and `cat()`.