# Where can I find documentation on the `..*..` ggplot options?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I use `..density..` from time to time, and it's great. There's lots of examples of it in the `ggplot2` book, as well as `..count..`. Looking through the [stat_density documentation](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/stat_density.html), I learned about `..scaled..`. Seeing someone use `..n..` here on StackOverflow, I found out about that. Now I just wonder what else I'm missing.

Search engines seem to ignore the `.`s in search strings like "..n.. ggplot2", even if I escape them. Is there a general term for these variables? Are there more? Where can I find documentation on them?

Comment: Well, go through the docs for all the `stat_*` functions and look under "value".

Comment: You can also use SymbolHound for special characters. (http://www.symbolhound.com/?q=..count..)

Comment: Appreciate the SymbolHound link, but it is interesting that it only brings up SO links and not any links to "real" R documentation pages.

Comment: Google allows some punctuation to be searched for but not periods:https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433

Comment: +1. I was wondering the same thing. And searching for those commands is such a pain... Also, thanks for the link, Jerome.

Comment: @42-: SymbolHound is only as good as us users make it, please [contact them](http://symbolhound.com/contact.php) and suggest them some sites to add to their indexing for R. I just contacted them and suggested they add *rdocumentation.org, r-bloggers.com, cran.r-project.org, r-statistics.co, www.rstudio.com, datacamp.com* etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of ggplot2 version 3.3.0 (2020-03-05), (from the changelog):

> The evaluation time of aesthetics can now be controlled to a finer degree. `after_stat()` supersedes the use of `stat()` and `..var..`-notation, and is joined by `after_scale()` to allow for mapping to scaled aesthetic values. Remapping of the same aesthetic is now supported with `stage()`, so you can map a data variable to a stat aesthetic, and remap the same aesthetic to something else after statistical transformation

So the `..var..` variables are moot, and you should try to research and use `after_stat` instead.

Answer (score 21):

Here are all of the `..*..` options mentioned in the **ggplot2** help files (or at least those help files that can be brought up by typing `?"<func>"`, where `"<func>"` refers to one of the functions exported by **ggplot2**).

```
library(ggplot2)

## Read all of the ggplot2 help files and convert them to character vectors
ex <- unlist(lapply(ls("package:ggplot2"), function(g) {
    p = utils:::index.search(g, find.package(), TRUE)
    capture.output(tools::Rd2txt(utils:::.getHelpFile(p)))
}))

## Extract all mentions of "..*.." from the character vectors
pat <- "\\.\\.\\w*\\.\\."
m <- gregexpr(pat, ex)    
unique(unlist(regmatches(ex,m)))
# [1] "..density.."  "..count.."    "..level.."    "..scaled.."   "..quantile.."
# [6] "..n.."
```

Or, to find out which help files document which `..*..`, run this:

```
library(ggplot2)

ex <- sapply(ls("package:ggplot2"), function(g) {
    p = utils:::index.search(g, find.package(), TRUE)
    capture.output(tools::Rd2txt(utils:::.getHelpFile(p)))
}, simplify=FALSE, USE.NAMES=TRUE)

res <- lapply(ex, function(X) {
    m <- gregexpr("\\.\\.\\w*\\.\\.", X)    
    unique(unlist(regmatches(X, m)))
})
res[sapply(res, length) > 0]
```

Comment: Bravo. Nicely done. Access to the text of the help documents will be very useful.

Comment: @DWin -- Well, thanks! I have to give credit to Yihui, [from whose gist](https://github.com/yihui/knitr-examples/blob/master/021-ggplot2-geoms.Rnw) (inspired by [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11653573/automated-ggplot2-example-gallery-in-knitr/11657083#11657083)) I first picked up some of those functions.