# R ggplot2 stat_density_2d has a "..level.." feature, what other features are available?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've recently learned about the `..level..` feature of `stat_density_2d()`. For example:

```
plot_data <-
  data.frame(X = c(rnorm(300, 3, 2.5), rnorm(150, 7, 2)),
             Y = c(rnorm(300, 6, 2.5), rnorm(150, 2, 2)),
             Label = c(rep('A', 300), rep('B', 150)))

ggplot(plot_data, aes(X, Y)) + 
  stat_density_2d(geom = "polygon", aes(alpha = ..level.., fill = Label))
```

[image]

I searched both the ggplot2 [github](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/) and the [reference documentation](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_density_2d.html) , and can not find sources for `..level..` and if there are additional interesting `..dotdot..` "hidden" features.

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17502808/double-dots-in-a-ggplot

Comment: As of ggplot2 version 3.3.0, the `..var..` variables are superseded, and the preferred way is to use `after_stat()`.

Comment: This answer worked in a previous version of ggplot2 - https://stackoverflow.com/a/18622577/10276092 - however, now the documentation does not contain any references to "..anything..".